# iOS Swift - How to flawlessly skip around an audio song with AVFoundation library?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, audio-player

So what I want to do is essentially skip around a song audio file automatically, such as it would skip from 5 seconds to 20 seconds and later 30 seconds to 80 seconds, but I want the skip to be flawless in sound because every time I change currentTime in an AVAudioPlayer instance, I hear a small static sound (pause) before the audio starts playing at the specified time. What I want to do is completely eliminate that small pause when using currentTime to skip around a track. Is there a better way to do this?

```
let player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
player.prepareToPlay()
player.play()

... Some time later
player.currentTime = XX
```

Comment: Did you try `seek`?

Comment: @matt AVAudioPlayer does not have a `seek` function

Comment: Oh, darn, you're right. I was thinking AVPlayer.

Comment: @matt no worries, would using seek with AVPlayer work better you think?

Comment: No idea, it was just a suggestion to try. The trouble here is that with all media things take time. But maybe seek doesn't audibly pause while the playhead repositions; I didn't try it.